# Joint Distribution and Conditional Expectations

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm looking for a joint distribution $f(X, Y)$ over two real-valued variables $X$ and $Y$ which take on values between $0$ and $1$, such that
$$
\forall x, y \in [0,1]^2 \quad f(X=x, Y=y) > 0
$$
and
$$
E[X \mid Y=y] = y
$$
and
$$
E[Y \mid X=x] = x
$$
Can anybody provide some simple distributions with these properties?

Comment: Example: $$P(X=Y)=1$$

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should be more specific: I want the p.d.f. $f$ to be positive for all values of $x$ and $y$ inside the unit square.  I've updated the question.

Comment: And what are the tries / thoughts / analogies that came to your mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we have
$$\mathbb{E}(X(X-Y))=\mathbb{E}(E[X(X-Y)\mid X]) = \mathbb{E}(X\times 0) = 0$$
Similarly,
$$\mathbb{E}(Y(X-Y))=\mathbb{E}(E[Y(X-Y)\mid Y]) = \mathbb{E}(Y\times 0) = 0$$ 
Therefore $\mathbb{E}((X-Y)(X-Y)) = \mathbb{E}((X-Y)^2) = 0$, so $P(X=Y) = 1$, and it's impossible for $P(X = x, Y = y)$ to be positive for all $x$ and $y$.